# How to access values in nested XML in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, web, fetch

I'm working with the following XML string in PHP and I want to access specific values from it.

For example: how can I extract the value of the title?

Below is my XML content:

```html
<record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <leader>01118cam a22003497i 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">18475363</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20151007123810.0</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">141017s2014    ii            000 f eng d</controlfield>
  
  <datafield tag="245" ind1="1" ind2="0">
    <subfield code="a">Half girlfriend /</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">Chetan Bhagat.</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="264" ind1=" " ind2="1">
    <subfield code="a">New Delhi :</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Rupa,</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">2014.</subfield>
  </datafield>
  </record>
```

How am I supposed to get the values "Half girlfriend" or "New Delhi"?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried so far?

Comment: So far . i've tried to convert the XML into PHP array first and then access the record manually from it .. `$value=simplexml_load_string($final_marc);
$json  = json_encode($value);

$configData = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($configData);`  But no luck so far and i think it's the wrong approach.

Comment: `final_marc` is the variable holding my xml string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath with the document you have, you can extract data with a combination of limiters.  If you know your going to need the data where in the datafield element - the tag value is 245, and the subfield code is "a" then you can do something like...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$final_marc = <<< XML
<record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <leader>01118cam a22003497i 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">18475363</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20151007123810.0</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">141017s2014    ii            000 f eng d</controlfield>

  <datafield tag="245" ind1="1" ind2="0">
    <subfield code="a">Half girlfriend /</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">Chetan Bhagat.</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="264" ind1=" " ind2="1">
    <subfield code="a">New Delhi :</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Rupa,</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">2014.</subfield>
  </datafield>
  </record>
XML;
$value=simplexml_load_string($final_marc);
$value->registerXPathNamespace("d","http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim");
echo "245-a".$value->xpath("//d:datafield[@tag='245']/d:subfield[@code='a']/text()")[0].PHP_EOL;
echo "264-a".$value->xpath("//d:datafield[@tag='264']/d:subfield[@code='a']/text()")[0].PHP_EOL;
```

As you have a default namespace, this is registered with the document and in this case I've defined 'd' as the prefix for convenience.  Then in the XPath you put the d in front of the element name.  The @tag bit is saying that the attribute value = 264 (for example) or the code attribute is 'a'.

Comment: can you please explain me this line `$value->registerXPathNamespace("d","http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim");`

Comment: When using XPath, you need to define any namespaces that you are using in the queries.  As this document has a default namespace (which doesn't have a prefix in normal elements) I've used 'd' as a convenient value.  In the subsequent XPath expressions, you put 'd:' in front of the element name to show that you want elements in the specific namespace.